# AngularJS 1.5 components binding data to controller and view with template url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-components

I want to achieve two way data binding between the view and the controller who glued by the component in AngularJS version 1.5.

The main purpose is to make a page (which is a component by itself)
to handle sub-components accessing referred data.

For example, I have page name: `Dashboard`.

I want that this page will contain `HeaderComponent` `ListComponent` and a `FooterComponent`.

And I want to pass data from the Dashboard component or from the root component ($rootScope) to the ListComponent for example,

like this:

```
<list-component key="123"></list-component>
```

However I cannot find a way to access the `key` attribute in the ListComponent either component or controller.

This is what I have tried:

```
// list.js component

app.component('listComponent', {
  templateUrl: "/shared/list/list.html",
  bindings: {
    key: '='
  },
  controller: function() {
    console.log(key);
    // or maybe
    console.log(this.key);
  }
});
```

Later I will use the `key` in the HTML with AngularJS default directives as a two way data binding. But so far I cannot access the `key` attribute yet.

Thank you ;)

Comment: In general with components, avoid two-way binding. Instead use one-way binding with `<` for inputs and expression binding with `&` for outputs. This will make the migration to Angular 2+ easier. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based application architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture).

Comment: The two-way binding with `key="123"` will fail with an error. See [AngularJS Error Reference - Error: $compile:nonassign
Non-Assignable Expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nonassign).

Comment: I do not understand. Lets say that in HeaderComponent I want to display 1 2 3 options for user A while I want to display 4 5 6 options for user B.
Then, when user a makes action with option 2 (which is dedicated only for him), I want to process that action in the HeaderComponent itself, rather than in the DashbordComponent. But I want that the executed data from HeaderComponent will be accessible as just as if it was created directly in the DashboardComponent. Otherwise, all of the functions are still relay in the DashboardComponent, and I wanna leave him almost blank.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have finally found the solution.

```
app.directive("datepickerComponent", () => {
  return {
    templateUrl: "/shared/datepicker/datepicker.html",
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      datepickerComponent(scope, element, attrs)
    }
  }
});

function datepickerComponent(scope, element, attrs) {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using onInit event handler:

```
controller: function () {
                this.$onInit = function() {
                    console.log(this.key);
                };
}
```

Comment: Yes, @raz you can access the property using $onInit.

Comment: Okay that is nice, now I can I return data created in the list component? For example, a user added a new item to the list, I need this to be returned to the main Dashboard component. How to do such a thing?

Comment: BTW If I am doing something this.key else than console log, I receive an error: Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression '123' in attribute 'key' used with directive 'listComponent' is non-assignab

Answer (score 0):

To access the `key` attribute as a string, use attribute binding with `@`:

```
<list-component key="123"></list-component>
```

```
app.component('listComponent', {
  templateUrl: "/shared/list/list.html",
  bindings: {
    ̶k̶e̶y̶:̶ ̶'̶=̶'̶
    key: '@'
  },
  controller: function() {
    this.$onInit = function() {
      console.log(this.key); // 123
    };
  }
});
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based application architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture)
- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-)
- [AngularJS API Reference - Directive Controller Life-Cycle Hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks)